extensions exist on remote box , but are shown as missing; extensions.json is an empty list
I have a VirtualBox instance (Debian12) under Windows which serves as an Ansible controller.
I want to use it from Windows via VSCode ssh-remote and have a hard time to install any extensions on the remote box.
VSCode is
Version: 1.88.1 (system setup)
Commit: e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39
Date: 2024-04-10T17:41:02.734Z
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
The extensions seem to exist:
norbert@ansible-vb-pelikan:~/.vscode-server$ ls extensions/
extensions.json  ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0  ms-python.python-2024.4.1  ms-python.vscode-pylance-2024.4.1  redhat.ansible-24.4.0  redhat.vscode-yaml-1.14.0

extensions.json is an empty list:
cat  extensions/extensions.json 
[]

When I start the connection vscode shows the extensions as missing for several minutes, consider the attached screenshoz
Then after a long time the extensions show up as installed .
What is up ere ? How can I investigate further ?
I copied some extensions over to the remote host and thought they would be installed.
I also set  "remote.downloadExtensionsLocally": true.
The network connection of the remote box seems to be fine in IPV4 and IPV6
Thanks for your consideration !
Norbert

It was indeed a network problem. The IPV6 connection was flaky and IPV6 seems to be preferred if it exists
